# If I have 3 A's and 4 B's how many unique strings can I make?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

AB, BA, ABBB, are all examples of unique strings I can make. Also, how many strings are there with unique letter make-ups? In other words AB and BA would be considered the same and only count as one. Is there a general way to do this if I have    $n_1$A's,   $n_2$B's, .... $n_n$◊'s?

Comment: ${7!}\over {3!4!}$.  second part $2^7$ if varying but you have $3$ A's, $4$ B's.  general is total! over # of each kind! as their orders do not matter

Answer (score 2):

For unique letter make-ups, we can select any number from $0$ to $n_1$ A's, $0$ to $n_2$ B's and so on, making the number of ways $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(n_i+1)$$

Subtract $1$ if you don't want to include the empty string.

For unique strings, I have not found a simple closed form yet.

Comment: Not quite related, but just couldn't help mentioning. This is just like the number of divisors ($\sigma (n)$) for a number of the form $n={p_1}^{n_1} \cdot {p_2}^{n_2} \cdot \cdot \cdot {p_k}^{n_k}$, where $p_i$'s are prime.

Comment: So let's say I have 2 A's and 2 B's. I have 1) the empty string, 2) A, 3) B 4) AA 5)BB and 6)AB. Your solution says I would have 9....( $(2+1) * (2+1) = 9 $)

Comment: You still have AAB, ABB, AABB.

Answer (score 1):

You can have four strings with no B.  "", "A", "AA", "AAA". (4 so far)

To add one B, there is one  place to add the B in "", So 1 of length 1.  There are two places to add the B in "A", So 2 of length 2.  Three places to add the B in "AAA", and four places to add the B in "AAA".  So we have 3 or length 3 and 4 of length 4.  (4 more strings or eight so far).

To add two B we add on to the strings with one B.  2 ways to add it to the 1 of length 1; 3 ways to add it to the 2 strings of length 2, and so on. But we are double counting so we must divide by 2.   These are 1 of length 2, 3 or length 3, 6 of length 4, 10 of length five (24 more; 32 so far.)

To add a third b:  1 way for length 3; 4 of length 4; 10 of length 5; 20 of length 6 (35 more; 67 so far.)

To add the 4th B: 1 of length 4, 5 of length 5; 15 of length 6; 35 of length 7 (51 more).

There are 118 posible strings including an empty string.

Not sure how to write that as sum but for m As and n Bs in general it would be the sum:

1  + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.......+ 1

1  + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 .......+ n

1  + 3 + 6 + 10 + 15 ......+ $\sum_{i=1}^n i$

1  + 4 + 10 + 20 + 35 .....+ $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i j$

.....

1  + m  + $\sum i$ + $\sum\sum i$ + .... + $\sum\sum\sum...$

(I hope)

Fortunately figuring out the number without regard to order is much easier.  You can have 0 to 3 As (4 choices) and 0 to 4 Bs (5 choices) so 20 total (including the empty string).

In general if you have $n_1$ As, $n_2$ Bs, $n_3$ Cs, etc.  you will have $\prod(n_i + 1)$ possible strings without regard to order and including the empty string.

Comment: I think this is compatible with Will Ps answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you had to use all 7:

(4+3)! / (4! * 3!) = 7*6*5 / (3*2*1) = 35

Reasoning: The first A can go in 7 positions, the second A in 6, the third A has 5 position to chose, makes 7*6*5; but the A's are all equal so you need to divide by 3*2*1 to discount the duplicates.

Repeat it for 6 letter 'words' [(6*5*4)/(3*2*1) = 20], 5-letter words, etc. and then add them all together.

The general answer would be:

(n1+n2+n3+...)! / (n1! * n2! * ...) for full length, etc.

Comment: I wrote further down: Repeat it for 6 letter words. Then for 5 and so on. Basically, this solution needs to be repeated for all word lengths 1, 2,3, 4,5, 6,7, and then totaled up.

Comment: You're right for 7 but not for lower amounts. Think about it for 6 letter words..I can just use 2 A's if I want.

Comment: Yep. I see it now - you wouldn't have to use all three As.